# Showing Circluar Progress bar in full screen in flutter inside a Future Builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

The below code shows my future builder which make an API call and return data. I want the CircularProgressIndicator to take the entire screen of the device. Issue is the future builder is inside the page view which is not taking the entire scree. Any idea to make the progress bar in a full screen?

Thanks in advance.

```
 Widget serverRequest(HomeViewModel vm, int position) {
return FutureBuilder(
  future: vm.fetchList(
      vm.getDataList.length, NUMBER_OF_ARTICLES_PER_PAGE),
  builder: (context, projectSnap) {
    if (projectSnap.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      return ThreeArticleItem();
    } else
      return Container(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
  },
);
```

}

Comment: @some user size should be customizable but it should freeze the full screen. Untill the data comes from the API. page view scroll should not happen

Comment: @some user that won't work because page view starts below the tab view and ends above the bottom navigation bar. I need some way to override it, so that it takes the full screen

Comment: What I would suggest is to wrap the entire widget that you wish to freeze with IgnorePointer till FutureBuilder is not complete. Something like this IgnorePointer(
 ignoring: true,
 child: WidgetToFreeze(),
)

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the code below. The CircularProgressIndicator is shown in the middle of the screen. The user cannot interact with any widget below the CircularProgressIndicator till the future is complete. IgnorePointer widget is used to stop user events till the future completes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = const Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool ignoring = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Flutter Demo"),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            IgnorePointer(
              ignoring: ignoring,
              child: ListView(
                  children: List.generate(
                      30, (index) => ListTile(title: Text("Tile # $index")))),
            ),
            FutureBuilder<bool>(
              future: Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 10), () {
                setState(() => ignoring = false);
                return true;
              }),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return (snapshot.hasData)
                    ? const Offstage()
                    : const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```